# Phone number not return Twitter digits sign in

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

I am working on twiiter digits in codeigniter web applicatiom,After login I got response similar like this ,Can you tell me how to retrive phone number.

> OAuth oauth_consumer_key="3R2jPNbiZ7lB2zUvDG3VmYIlU",
>   oauth_nonce="773391896567812097-wGawMEgkxrzRhjCHmgPf5UnWOKWgVFV3R2jPNbiZ7lB2zUvDG3VmYIlU1473233637358",
>   oauth_signature="qPmcftNzOrtyh3MCzeGaTeVsSmE%3D",
>   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1473233637",
>   oauth_token="773391896567812097-wGawMEgkxrzRhjCHmgPf5UnWOKWgVFV",
>   oauth_version="1.0"

Can you guys tell mewhere to get phone number..

Comment: Please proof read before posting - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

1. which api and sdk are you using?
2. are you aware that digits is being retired and you are encouraged to use Firebase phone authentication?
3. Please read more about it here http://get.digits.com/blog/introducing-firebase-phone-authentication